# PHP, Webpage has a redirect Loop

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-headers

I  am   developing a small website that a  user would be  able  to  use to hold  customer  information and records of  sales. For security reasons a user should only be  able to view the home page or any page once they are logged in. Therefore I have  made  a redirect statement at the  top of my header.php file that will redirect the user to the  login page if they  are not logged in. The  problem is  now  I  am faced with an infinite  loop of redirecting. I am not sure  where to put the redirect so that it will not create  an   infinite  loop.

Here is my header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: login.php');
    } 
    ?>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Shawn's Goods - <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' />
</head>

<body>

    <?php  session_start(); ?>

    <?php 
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    ?>

        <div class="headerWrapper">

            <h1 class="pageHeader">Shawn's Goods</h1>

            <div class="userFunctions">

                <a class="usernameDisplay"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></a>
                <a class="logoutButton">Logout</a>

            </div>

        </div>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

This is an include file that is included in all  my pages. I  read somewhere that a header() php function must be  placed before the html tag of a page, Im not sure  if that is correct ?

Another solution would be  to write a php function that  checks if the   username  is set and then   either prints the code for the login page or for the home page but I would still need  some sort of login redirect if a user manually typed  in the address of the  customer page for example.

Here is my login script :

common.php:

```
<?php 

    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'Change01&';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'shaunsgoods';

    $hi = 'Hello';

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

    try {

        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {

        die("DBErr");
    }

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

     if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    session_start();
```

loginscript.php:

```
<?php 

    require('common.php');

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    {

        if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
            die('UserErr');
        }

        if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
            die('PassErr');
        }

        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                role
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        ";

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        );

        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) { 
            die('DBErr '.$ex->getMessage()); 
        }

        $login_ok = false;

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok) { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];

            header('Location: home.php'); 
            die('Redirecting to: home.php');
        } 
        else { 
            die("LogErr"); 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: In your `header.php`, Move `start_session()` to the beginning. Just after opening tags of `php`

Comment: Explaining what @BasitSaeed said: Since `start_session()` hasn't been called yet the "server side cookies" (i'm dumbifying for explanation sake) aka `$_SESSION` array and its values are not created yet, therefore `(!isset($_SESSION['username']))` would always return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Just not defined session so run

```
header('Location: login.php');
```

move `session_start();`  to top of page so this is true code:

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
 if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: login.php');
    } 

?>
```